# Class Design in Java - a more elegant solution?

Tags: java, oop, class

```
public class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
    private ClickGrid grid;

    public void registerMouseOutput(ClickGrid gridIN){}
    public void handleMouseInput(MouseEvent e){
        //Handle some mouse input
        grid.manipulateMouseData(e);
    }
}


public class ClickGrid {
    private boolean[][] 2darray = new boolean[3][2];
    private int[][] points_list = {{30, 100}, {200, 500}, {400, 300}};

    private GridDisplay gridDisplay;

    public void registerGridDisplay(GridDisplay griddisplayIN){
        gridDisplay = griddisplayIN;
        gridDisplay.setClickGrid(this);
    }
    public void manipulateMouseData(MouseEvent e) {
        //Do certain things based on mouse data
        gridDisplay.updateDisplay();
    }
}    

public class GridDisplay extends JPanel {
    private ClickGrid clickgrid;

    public void setClickGrid(ClickGrid clickgridIN){}
    public void updateDisplay(){}

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(){
        //display image at clickgrid.getPointsList(x,y) 
        //if clickgrid.get2dArray(x,y) is true;
    }
}
```

It seems like I am daisy-chaining these classes (they only work with each other, and not generally) and they are becoming too specific.

I could inherit ClickGrid from a base class that just implemented part of the functionality, but then I only have one chance to abstract some functionality (no multiple inheritance). I could repeatedly inherit for each new functionality, but how do know which functionalities are more fundamental?

I'm not a perfectionist and this solution works, but as I was coding I was thinking "this feels clunky. There must be more intelligent ways of doing this." I have a lot of these sorts of design problems, though.

Comment: Good question but it will likely be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ which is meant for these types of questions where there isn't a definite answer. It is a good place to ask for code reviews and other more 'touchy-feely' stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately, most swing applications "feel clunky" and I haven't found any good ways to address this. I have found that in all the swing apps I have worked on, you usually end up in one of the following two scenarios: a) a bunch of tightly coupled controls which makes it hard to make changes OR b) some over-generalized hierarchy which does everything through 7 levels of indirection and just over-complicates things and, once again, makes it hard to change.

Comment: My only suggestions are to make good use of descriptive variable/method names, extract methods to avoid duplication, and keep it as simple as possible. Anything to make it easier for you to change later...